# configure: error: No working boost sleep implementation found

Tags: boost, bitcoin-testnet, qubit

we are using that commands in my vps Server
my server configuration is:

- 2 GB Memory / 50 GB Disk / NYC1 - Ubuntu 14.04.5 x64

This is for VPS.

---

```
./autogen.sh

./configure --with-miniupnpc --enable-wallet  --enable-upnp-default --disable-tests --enable-hardening --enable-debug --with-libressl CPPFLAGS="-I/home/theusername/bitcoin/db4/include -O2" LDFLAGS="-L/home/theusername/bitcoin/db4/lib" CXXFLAGS="--param ggc-min-expand=1 --param ggc-min-heapsize=32768" SSL_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/openssl/include  SSL_LIBS=-L/usr/local/openssl/lib  CRYPTO_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/openssl/include  CRYPTO_LIBS=-L/usr/local/openssl/lib --with-boost="/usr/include/boost" --with-boost-libdir="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"

make
```

After make command we getting this error (configure: error: No working boost sleep implementation found.)

Comment: Nice of you to show the commands. However, what are you compiling? Can you add some context as well as output?

Comment: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/5016